# BIRT is missing SOAP request parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, birt

I setup a running webservice (SOAP via JAX-WS) which has already some working Java and C# clients without any issues.

When I try to use the same SOAP webservice with BIRT I found out that in the generated request it is missing the parameters for the functions.

How can I help BIRT find the missing method parameters?

**Generated Request (Missing parameter)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:getMachine xmlns:m="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
        </m:getMachine>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Request that I would expect (With parameter)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:getMachine xmlns:m="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">
            <m:machineId>&?machineId?&</m:machineId>
        </m:getMachine>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**WSDL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01. -->
<definitions
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
    xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    targetNamespace="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/"
    name="WSMachineApiService">

    <types>
        <xs:schema 
            xmlns:tns="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            version="1.0"
            targetNamespace="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/">

            <xs:element name="InvalidIdException" type="tns:InvalidIdException"></xs:element>

            <xs:element name="getMachine" type="tns:getMachine"></xs:element>

            <xs:element name="getMachineResponse" type="tns:getMachineResponse"></xs:element>

            <xs:complexType name="getMachine">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="machineId" type="xs:string" form="qualified"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="getMachineResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="return" type="tns:WSMachine" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="WSMachine">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="totalShots" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="totalEvents" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="actualData" type="tns:WSMachineActualData" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="WSMachineActualData">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="connected" type="xs:boolean"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="operationMode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="moldData" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="cycleTime" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="totalProduction" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="currentProduction" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="remainingProduction" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="rejectedParts" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="remainingTime" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="InvalidIdException">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>

    </types>

    <message name="getMachine">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getMachine"></part>
    </message>

    <message name="getMachineResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getMachineResponse"></part>
    </message>

    <message name="InvalidIdException">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:InvalidIdException"></part>
    </message>

    <portType name="WSMachineApi">
        <operation name="getMachine">
            <input wsam:Action="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/WSMachineApi/getMachineRequest" message="tns:getMachine"></input>
            <output wsam:Action="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/WSMachineApi/getMachineResponse" message="tns:getMachineResponse"></output>
            <fault message="tns:InvalidIdException" name="InvalidIdException" wsam:Action="http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/WSMachineApi/getMachine/Fault/InvalidIdException"></fault>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="WSMachineApiPortBinding" type="tns:WSMachineApi">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"></soap:binding>
        <operation name="getMachine">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </input>

            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </output>

            <fault name="InvalidIdException">
                <soap:fault name="InvalidIdException" use="literal"></soap:fault>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="WSMachineApiService">
        <port name="WSMachineApiPort" binding="tns:WSMachineApiPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/services/Machines"></soap:address>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**WS- Implementation**

```
package at.company.product.webservices.soap.machine;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

import at.company.product.core.ProductCorePlugin;
import at.company.product.core.machine.IMachine;
import at.company.product.webservices.soap.exceptions.InvalidIdException;


@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class WSMachineApi {

    @WebMethod
    public WSMachine getMachine(
            @WebParam(name = "machineId", targetNamespace = "http://machine.soap.webservices.product.company.at/")  @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false) String machineId) throws InvalidIdException {
        IMachine machine = getMachineById(machineId);
        if (machine == null) {
            throw new InvalidIdException(machineId);
        }

        return new WSMachine(getMachineById(machineId));
    }


    private IMachine getMachineById(String id) {
        return ProductCorePlugin.getDefault().getMachineHallAdmin().getMachineByID(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: This rings a bell I remember something similar with BIRT and SOAP and having to use some sort of HTTP component and not the SOAP one. WIll check if I have the code somewhere still.

Comment: That would be great if you can share your experience and a potential solution.

Comment: Apologies this was about three years ago and I was working with both Pentaho and BIRT. The problem I experienced was on the Pentaho side. I will check a bit more but I seemed to have muddled up the two in my head.